# How to create a form without any TitleBar?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, window

I am actually developing a UserControl that requires this kind of form.

Normally a WinForms Form looks like this:

[image]

If I set "FormBorderStyle = None", it looks like this:

[image]

But, I actually need a window without TitleBar like the following:

[image]

Please see the difference at the edge of the window. It actually looks more like a context menu.

```
myForm.Text="";
myForm.ControlBox= false;
```

This solution leaves the TitleBar so that the form remains movable. This is a problem.

I actually need this: the user click the button and the form appears like the following:

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a form at all. Consider a UserControl.

Comment: I am actually developing a UserControl that requires this kind of form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
yourForm.Text="";

yourForm.ControlBox= false;
```

and in properties, change : `FormBorderStyle` to :`FixedDialog`

Answer (score 1):

To get like that then do not set any title text and make controlbox visible false

like this

```
yourForm.Text="";
yourForm.ControlBox= false;
```